# Using window.opener.location to access a non-secure (http) opener from a secure (https) pop up

Tags: javascript, https, window.opener

I am opening a popup which is under https from a web page which is under http. When I try to use the command window.opener.location.(href/str/port/domain.. etc) from the pop-up to get the url of the opener page, I get a 'Permission Denied'. Ive also been using Firebug on Firefox to test this out.
Is there any way I can by pass this by using another command or doing something else.
If I open the opener url under https, then I am able to access it from the pop-up. I am guessing this has to be with being on a secure port as compared to a non-secure one. I was thinking that this should be possible since I am trying to get the information of a non-secure page from a secure page.

Basically, I am trying to scan the url of the opener page and check if it contains a certain substring, I want to perform a certain function. Any alternative suggestions to achieving this would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You see the error because of Same Origin Policy. When two domains compared it takes into consideration protocol, domain name and port. In your case protocols are different therefore you get "Permission denied" exception.
You may try the following trick - when you open the popup, assign parent's url to popup `window.name`, which should be available for the in-popup javascript. In addition you may construct url of your popup with hash at the end, for example: `https://mydomain.com/page.html#http://mydomain.com/parent.html`

There are [couple other tricks you may perform to bypass SOP](http://easyxdm.net/wp/).